# Multi user chat's invitation not being received.

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, openfire

first i create user then i send invitation to users. and i also attached a listener of Multi user chat listener.  invitation sent but not receiving in other device.

```
    String jid = groupname + "@" + "conference.domain";
                    MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).getMultiUserChat(jid)
        .create(Resourcepart.from(nick)).makeInstant();

        s = "othersid" + "@" + "domain";

     getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(jid)).invite(getEntityBareJid(s), "");
```

Invitation listener attached at login time.

```
 MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).
    .addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
                @Override
                public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection conn, MultiUserChat room, EntityJid inviter, String reason, String password, Message message, MUCUser.Invite invitation) {
                 room.join(room.getNickname());}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the stanza that your custom code send, and a stanza sent by a well-known client that works correctly.

For example, you can sniff the traffic with a program like this. Then user your client, and later use another client that works correctly (like Psi, Gajim, Tkabber...). Search for the invitation stanza, and compare it.

Example sniffer:

> tcpflow -i lo -Cg port 5222